# Why are my functions public?

Tags: javascript, scope, singleton, closures

I asked a similar question a couple of days ago but I guess I'm still doing something wrong, so this one is more focused:

As far as I understand and according to [this book](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript), the function `privateFunction` is supposed to not be available from outside the `mySingleton` object, where `publicFunction` can only be called this way: `mySingleton.publicFunction`.

However - privateFunction is very available outside of the object against my will and intent.

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

```
    var mySingleton = new (function (window, document, undefined) {

            var privateFunction = function () {
                //code
            },

            mySingleton = {
                publicFunction: function () {
                    //code
                }
            };

        return mySingleton;
    })(window, document, undefined);
```

EDIT: I just found the problem. Syntax error, how humiliating. Take a look at the semicolon on line 2. I missed out on this line when I was posting last night:

```
    var mySingleton = new (function (window, document, undefined) {
        var self = this;

        privateFunction = function () {
            //code
        },

        mySingleton = {
            publicFunction: function () {
                //code
            }
        }

        return mySingleton ;
    })(window, document, undefined);
```

Replacing the semicolon with a comma makes the private methods private "again". Regardless, looking at this code I would expect such a syntax to cause a syntax error, because of the comma right after `privateFunction` - am I getting this all wrong?

Comment: Are you running this in a browser? Can you show an example that makes you think this is public?

Comment: I don't actually understand why you would actually need a private function in JavaScript...

Comment: @Der - For the same reason you need a private function anywhere: because you have some internal mechanism that isn't part of the public interface.

Comment: @pilau: The function is not available publicly. http://jsfiddle.net/3RwgQ/

Comment: As user1689607's fiddle demonstrates, the function is not available in global scope, nor can it be accessed by `mySingleton.privateFunction()`. Please show more code to demonstrate the problem you are having. Unrelated to that, why are you using `new` on the first line? Also unrelated, on the last line you probably want to pass just two arguments, `(window, document)`, because that ensures that within the function `undefined` definitely will be undefined - this mechanism is used to protect against cases where other global code has set `undefined` to some other value.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Yes this is a browser code. I have updated the question with further details and would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Variables declared without the `var` keyword are considered global variables. That's why it's not a syntax error - it's a valid global variable declaration.

Comment: And about the comma. It's a valid operator. The comma operator works like this: given two statements (and variable assignments are statements) execute both and return the result of the second statement. So, it's valid syntax still.

Comment: Everyday you learn something new :) Do you mind putting that in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever seen this kind of code?

```
var toto = 'titi',
    titi = 'tata',
    tata = 'toto';
```

This is multiple assignments. This allows us to not reuse the `var` keyword every time. However, since you're not using the `var` keyword, `privateMethod` is actually leaked to the global scope. That's bad.

I think you're looking for this pattern:

```
var mySingleton = function() {
    function privateMethod() {}

    return {
        publicMethod: function() {}
    };
}();
```

The `window`, `document` and `undefined` crap is not needed.

Comment: I thought that every variable defined within a function is in the scope of that function (and it's children) only? Edit: slebetman answered this question in the comments above.

Comment: Why are the window, document and undefined parameters unnecessary?

Comment: @pilau for the parameters: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/iife-argument-madness/

Comment: Actually there are many opinions in favor of taking this approach in the comments section of this very article